# Making an Ajax call inside a singleton class constructor

Tags: ajax, extjs, constructor, singleton, sencha-touch-2

With Sencha Touch, I have defined a singleton class with an Ajax call inside its constructor. When my apps start I get the error message : **Cannot call method 'request' of undefined** from the line  with "Ext.Ajax.request".

If I remove the Ajax call inside the constructor my application will load without any error.

Then, if I make my Ajax call inside another function that is called after my application has started it works. So I presume that Ext.Ajax is not yet loaded when the constructor function is called. I have tried to add the **uses** parameter to my class but it does not work.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.utils.PostalCode', {
    singleton: true,
    config : {
        postalCodesHashMap : null,  
    },  
    uses : 'Ext.Ajax',
    constructor: function(config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            //will not work        
        }); 
    },  
    loadData : function() {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            //will work             
        }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: @jprofitt : It works, thank you! You can make an answer and I will chose it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `uses`, you'll want to use `requires` to indicate that `Ext.Ajax` will be needed prior to this class being created.

```
requires: ['Ext.Ajax']
```

What was likely happening was that something else along the way required `Ext.Ajax`, so the `loadData()` request had access to it without `MyApp.utils.PostalCode` explicitly asking for it to be loaded first.